# ASP.NET Listview with multiple headings

Tags: asp.net, listview

Hey I was wondering how could I create a listview which had multiple headings..i.e

Heading 1

Details template
Details template
Details template

Heading 2

Details template
Details template

Comment: As in nested listviews? Or two totally seperate listviews?

Comment: I guess nestled listview yeah..imagine you have Sport Athletes who you want to display in the listview but they come under different categories..Amateur, Pro and Retired and you want a different header template for each category in listview

Comment: And there will be multiple rows under each header?

Answer (score 0):

U can use Parent and child list view in Parent list view main heading comes and in child list view remaining headings comes.